# Mifare Ultralight data access

Tags: permissions, tags, nfc, mifare

I am using NFC TagInfo to read a MIFARE Ultralight tag. Some pages have the following access rights:

> **readable writable locked**
>   and
>   **readable writable un-locked**

What is the difference between them? If they are readable writable what is locked/unlocked about them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the possible values for access rights displayed by [NFC TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo) for NXP MIFARE Ultralight (all variants), Infineon my-D and other NFC Forum Type 2 tags:

- **writable (not locked)**: page is writable and the lock bit can be modified (i.e. the page can still be locked to read-only)
- **writable (locked)**: page is writable and the lock bit is locked (i.e. the page cannot be locked to read-only anymore)
- **partially writable**: parts of the page are factory read-only while parts are writable (e.g. pages containing lock bits)
- **partially writable (not locked)**: one-time writable memory and lock bit can be modified (i.e. the page can still be locked to read-only)
- **partially writable (locked)**: one-time writable memory and the lock bit is locked (i.e. the page cannot be locked to read-only anymore)
- **read-only (locked)**: page is set to read-only and the lock bit is locked (i.e. the page cannot be reversed to writable anymore)
- **read-only (factory locked)**: page is written once during manufacturing time and cannot be re-written later (e.g. the tag's serial number)
- **read / restricted write**: See my-D's read / restricted write mode
- **write-only (not locked)**: page is writable but cannot be read (possibly due to missing authentication) and lock bit can be modified (i.e. page can be changed to no access/authenticated read-only)
- **write-only (locked)**: page is writable but cannot be read (possibly due to missing authentication) and lock bit is locked (i.e. page cannot be locked to no access/authenticated read-only anymore)
- **no access (locked)**: page's lock bit indicates read-only but page cannot be read (possibly due to missing authentication) and lock bit is locked (i.e. page can be changed to writable anymore)
- **no access**: page contains this page's lock bits and cannot be read (possibly due to missing authentication)
- **unknown**: lock state for this page could not be determined (unknown tag type or lock bits not readable)

Comment: At least for NXP Ultralight and NTAG tags and NFC Forum Type 2 Tags in general, a page that is "locked" implies that it is read-only (there is no such thing as write-only for these tags). This state cannot be undone, as lock bits are write-once (OTP memory). The lock bytes themselves (i.e. the pages where the lock bits are stored)  can also be locked. That freezes the state of the tag. I assume that "writeable (locked)" implies such a state.

Comment: Correct, the lock state indicated in parentheses indicates the lock state of the lock bit whereas the read/write state (outside the parentheses) indicates the state of the page's lock bit.

Comment: Regarding write-only, you are correct: There is no such state with regular Ultralight, NTAG203 and Type 2 tags in general. However, there is such a state for Ultralight C, Ultralight EV1 and some other manufacturers' Type 2 tags. For instance the password pages of Ultralight C.

Comment: HI Sir Michael Roland ,I use Mifare Ultralight NFC tag I want to write one time read-only method lock page 4 to 7 and 8 to 12 page.how we can do it?

Comment: the following simple code lock page 3 to 15.I want to lock page 4 to 7 and 8 to 12 how we can do it?
      mifare.transceive(new byte[] {
        (byte)0xA2,  /* CMD = WRITE */
        (byte)0x02,  /* PAGE = 2    */
        (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF  /* DATA = lock pages   3..15*/
        });